# Unexpected behaviour with variable variables

Tags: php, scope, variable-variables

I was trying to pass a variable that contained the name of the superglobal array I wanted a function to process, but I couldn't get it to work, it would just claim the variable in question didn't exist and return null.

I've simplified my test case down to the following code:

```
function accessSession ($sessName)
{
    var_dump ($$sessName);
}

$sessName   = '_SERVER';

var_dump ($$sessName);

accessSession ($sessName);
```

The var_dump outside of the function returns the contents of $_SERVER, as expected.  However, the var_dump in the function triggers the error mentioned above.

Adding `global $_SERVER` to the function didn't make the error go away, but assigning $_SERVER to another variable and making that variable global did work (see below)

```
function accessSession ($sessName)
{
    global $test;
    var_dump ($$sessName);
}

$test       = $_SERVER;
$sessName   = 'test';

var_dump ($$sessName);

accessSession ($sessName);
```

Is this a PHP bug, or am I just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [**PHP: Variable variables - Manual**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

> **Warning**
>
> Please note that variable variables **cannot be used** with PHP's **Superglobal arrays within functions or class methods**. The variable $this is also a special variable that cannot be referenced dynamically.

---

### Solutions

```
function access_global_v1 ($var) {
  global    $$var;
  var_dump ($$var);
}
```

---

```
function access_global_v2 ($var) {
  var_dump ($GLOBALS[$var]);
}
```

---

```
$test = 123;

access_global_v1 ('_SERVER');
access_global_v2 ('test');
```

Answer (score 2):

From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

> **Warning**
>
> Please note that variable variables cannot be used with PHP's
>   Superglobal arrays within functions or class methods. The variable
>   $this is also a special variable that cannot be referenced
>   dynamically.

Answer (score -2):

The answer is fairly simple: **never use variable variables**.
Use **arrays** instead.

(and yes - you are doing something wrong. No, it is not a bug in PHP.)

Answer (score -2):

Use $GLOBALS. There you go :)

```
<?php

function accessSession ($sessName)
{
    var_dump ($GLOBALS[$sessName]);
}

$sessName   = '_SERVER';

accessSession ($sessName);
```